# Finding memory leaks in application using hugetlbfs

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am using hugetlbfs in one our projects.

Our project is in C/C++.

We suspect memory leaks in the application.

And tried valgrind and other tools like MEMWATCH, MTRACE and DMALLOC. But they didn't work out.

Can Anybody suggest a tool or modification(configuration changes) in the above tools to find memory leaks in the application that are using hugetlbfs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *How* didn't those tools work out? They (especially Valgrind) seems to work very fine for everybody else? Did you remember to build with debug information? Are you sure you actually *have* memory leaks? If none of the tools you used reported any memory leaks, then maybe you don't actually have any memory leaks?

Comment: When using valgrind, My application was dumping core because of no memory. Here valgrind is occupying the memory and my application fails to start. We are using 24GB of RAM. Still it is dumping cores.
Here is our program size.
[root@SCE10000 bin]# size fp_pd
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 614367    9288  237552  861207   d2417 fp_pd

Comment: But only when using Valgrind? It doesn't crash otherwise? Either your code is so bad it causes Valgrind to bug out (in which case you should report it to Valgrind), or you have other problems in your code (probably some undefined behavior) that needs to be fixed. Do you get *any* output from Valgrind? How about the other tools?

Comment: No. When trying without valgrind, application is fine. But usage of memory is continuously increasing. What I'm suspecting is valgrind is occupying memory and our application is running out of memory and crashing as a result.

Comment: How fast does the memory increase? If you're lucky, you can run under GDB or some other debugger and randomly break into the debugger. Inspect the threads (`info threads` in gdb) and hope that one of them is currently allocating. Go to that thread and print the stack trace (`where`). Not very scientific but it might work. Else run in valgrind and attach GDB (using valgrind's vgdb). Tell gdb to break on exceptions (`catch throw`), is should break when the `std::bad_alloc` is thrown.